# How to manage subplots in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0,-10,-1), 'B': range(10,20), 'C': range(10,30,2)})
```

and plot:

```
df[['A','B','C']].plot(subplots=True, sharex=True)
```

I get one column with 3 subplots, each even height.

How to plot it this way that I have only two subplots where 'A' is in upper one and 'B' and 'C' are in lower *and* lower graph's height is different than height of graph 'A' (x axis is shared)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subplots` with `gridspec_kw` parmater to setup your grid then use the `ax` paramter in pandas plot to use those axes defined in your subplots statement:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,2]})
df[['A','B','C']].plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, ax=[ax[0,0],ax[0,1],ax[1,0]])
ax[1,1].set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good solution. May I ask what does `ax[1,1].set_visible(False)` serve?

Comment: @HarvIpan Thank you. From my testing if you don't do that you get a 2x2 matrix with an empty axes in the lower right-hand corner.  So, I turn it off by setting visible to False.

Comment: Thanks. I modified this solution to my needs:


 f, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,3]})

f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

df[['A','B','C']].plot(subplots=True, ax=[ax[0],ax[1],ax[1]])

Comment: @ScottBoston, is there a way where we do not have to deal with it? May be just create 3 graphs?

Comment: @HarvIpan Yes, I think so, you have to set up gridspec to meet your exact needs.  This was a shortcut using subplot.  Look at matploblib [`Customizing Location of Subplot Using GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I post my modified code here:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,3]})
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
df[['A','B','C']].plot(subplots=True, ax=[ax[0],ax[1],ax[1]])
```

That will do it. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with [.subplot2grid()](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#basic-example-of-using-subplot2grid). Which only creates 3 plots as needed.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (0, 0), colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (0, 1), colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (1, 0), rowspan=2, sharex=ax1)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

ax1.plot(df['A'])
ax2.plot(df['B'], color='darkorange')
ax3.plot(df['C'], color='green')
```

Output:

[image]